# "Access violation writing location 0x00000000457E8770" Using malloc in C

Tags: c, malloc

I have the Error from above, I'll try to as clear as possible.

***short explanation:***

I'm defininng a new structure: **kid**, and I want to allocate space in the memory for a new array of type kid.
So I'm doing malloc (by my checks->didn't fail) and trying to write to one of the fields if the array, but I get the error in the title.
I don't understand why I can't write in those fields ,even though I did dynamic allocation .

***The code with comments:***

I defined a struct called kid as follow:

```
 typedef struct
 {
     char name[16];
     candy *kid_candy;
 } kid;
```

(candy is another struct I defined, i don't need it's neccesary to copy his definition)

The above definition is written in the h file that is included in the code below.

```
#include "kindergarten.h"
void AllocateKidsArray(int size);

int main()
{
    AllocateKidsArray(3);
}

void AllocateKidsArray(int size){

     kid *p_kids_arr = NULL;
     int i ;
     char blank[16] = {' '};

//In the next line want to allocate space for an array,that his type is kid:
     p_kids_arr = (kid*)malloc(size * sizeof(kid));

//  checking if allocation failed
     if (p_kids_arr == NULL)
     {
         return -1;
     }
     else
     {
         for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
         {

//now im trying to change a field in the array I allocated before:
             (p_kids_arr + sizeof(kid)*i)->kid_candy = NULL;
//but I always get the error from the title
         }

    }
}
```

***Summary:***

When I looked for a solution online most of the people who had that error,had it because they declared a pointer staitcly, and then tried to write into them.
But in my case I where Im doing malloc, i just cant figure out whats the problem, and It's disturbing, because It's looks like something fundamental.

It's very important for me to understand what's Im missing and what I'm doing wrong, I dont want any code fixing, all I want is to understand why cant I  write to fields I dynamically allocated,and that's why I need your help.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you multiply `i`  by `sizeof(kid)` when trying to access the array members?

Comment: Does your real code miss to include `<stdlib.h>` as well?

Comment: In C  one does not need to cast the result of `malloc()`. Just drop the `(kid*)`, as it's useless and most likely just hiding the real mistake.

Comment: "*something fundamental*" is pointer arithmetic. It seems to be time for [Binky](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/104/) again. :-) [The video is here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5VnDaHBi8dM).

Comment: Can you also show the missing definition?

Comment: "Does your real code miss to include <stdlib.h> as well? " 
Youre the man!!!! that was my problem thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Why not replace this

```
      (p_kids_arr + sizeof(kid)*i)->kid_candy = NULL;
```

with this:

```
      p_kids_arr[i].kid_candy = NULL;
```

The two above are not same. Because if I add 1 to a pointer of type `int` in reality due to pointer arithmetic you are adding 4 bytes (if size of int pointer is 4 bytes) to it (so the first version I think adds more bytes to `p_kids_arr`  than needed.)

Also as noted in comments it seems you are missing `#include <stdlib.h>`

and you should have received a warning since you are doing `return -1;` in a function which has return type `void`.

Comment: I tried this form before, didn't worked for me also.
thanks for helping

Comment: @albert1905 are you sure? maybe your problem was smth. else then?

Comment: Or just do: `(p_kids_arr + i)->kid_candy = NULL;`

Comment: @alk yes true, the sizeof seems redundant there.

Comment: @alk yeah in simple words by redundant I meant there is something which should not be there :)